# Int16 from buffer help (BE)

Tags: c++, short

Alright so here is my issue. I read two bytes from a file.

Lets say those bytes are "FD 37" - That should be: 64823

I am reading in big endian so I tried array reversing little endian and then trying bit movements. I do need help as I can't get this. Any help is appreciated.

(yes I know it's a ghetto array reverse..)

```
static void Reverse(BYTE* &buffer, long length)
{
    BYTE *obuff = new BYTE[length];
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        obuff[length-i-1] = buffer[i];
    obuff[length] = '\0';
    buffer = obuff;
}

typedef signed short int Int16;

Int16 ReadInt16()
{
    Int16 val;
    BYTE* bytes = new BYTE[2];
    Read(bytes, 0, 2); //just stores 2 bytes into bytes and advances buffer 2 positions.
    Array::Reverse(bytes,2);
    val = bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8);
    return val;
}
```

My outcome using that method is -753

any ideas?

Comment: `obuff[length] = '\0';` is a very bad idea to boot. The last element of the new array is `obuff[length-1]`. Also you don't need a `\0` at the end of an array if it's not a string.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote then when I was first learning. I'll use it! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an unsigned number you should use an unsigned type and not a signed one.

Comment: @user1425433, `0xfd37` doesn't fit in a signed 16 bit integer.

Comment: @user1425433 Just try it :)

Comment: @CarlNorum It windows calculator it works. Should I try shifting the bytes to an int instead?

Comment: @user1425433 Using `unsigned short` should be enough.

Comment: @user1425433 If `bytes` is `{0x37, 0xfd}`, what is `bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8)`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg wow that did work. I just had to cast at the end of the bit movement and it worked. Very helpful. Thankyou!

Comment: @user1425433 I recommend you read more about the difference between signed and unsigned types.